# Gulp sass not defining variables & mixins across all imports?

Tags: css, sass, gulp

I'm compiling my SCSS with gulp-scss. My styles.scss file looks like this:

```
@import "node_modules/bulma/sass/utilities/initial-variables";
@import "node_modules/bulma/bulma";
@import 'src/styles/navigation';
```

The second line of this code imports Bulma, the source code for which can be found [here](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/blob/master/bulma.sass). This file imports some [utilities](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/blob/master/sass/utilities/_all.sass), including some [mixins](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/blob/master/sass/utilities/mixins.sass) I need.

Unfortunately when I try to use those mixins in my `navigation.scss` file:

```
@include desktop {
  .navbar {
    min-height: 135px;
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

[image]

Worth noting that if I `@import` the mixins and variables file in `navigation.scss` directly, it works fine. What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with my file names. They were not preceeded by an underscore, which appears to be the convention for the compiler to work properly. So `src/styles/navigation.scss` became `src/styles/_navigation.scss`. The import remained the same:

```
@import 'src/styles/navigation';
```

Comment: Same here! Thanks for the answer! I think node-sass does not need the underscore.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume you use gulp-sass.

What I usually do is creating a path in the gulp file for better reference and also for letting know gulp I will be using these node resources in .scss files.

In this case I'm calling foundation and compass mixins modules in the include paths.

**This is a task in the Gulfile.js**

```
gulp.task('styles', function () {
  gulp.src('src/scss/application.scss')
    .pipe(sass({
      includePaths: [
       'node_modules/foundation-sites/scss',
       'node_modules/compass-mixins/lib'
      ],
      outputStyle: 'compressed'
    }).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css/'))
});
```

Then in your main .scss or where you want to place the import for those files you can just simply add:

```
@import 'compass';
@import 'foundation';
@include foundation-everything;
```

Here I call the compass file inside this node module path I specified in the gulp file, and also the foundation.scss (which imports a lot of other scss files). 
Then once foundation is availabe I initialize all the mixins.

**So summing up:**
Possible solutons:
1: Check if this gulpfile definition with include path solves you routes errors.
2: check if the modules you are importing don't have a trigger mixin to enable them, such as foundation has his "foundation-everything"

Hope this helps.